# Forward Application IP/host to localhost (windows)

Tags: windows, forwarding, application, address

I'm working on a windows XP / win 7 environment and i have an application (game) that connects to an static hostname and ip.

It does have a connection to 2 ports (ports 5000TCP&UDP and 6000TCP).

I have a local server running on same 2 ports working.

There is anyway, apart from editing hosts files, to forward the application calling to "hostname" to localhost?.

Host editing works, so my server does, but need it for people who cannot edit it.
Also, i have no access to sourcecode, just from outside.

thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 2):

It would be the simplest solution to just edit the HOSTS files.

There is no out-of-the-box solution for.

You might configure a DNS instance to point the NS Entry to localhost. But this would just be more complicated and would not bring any advantage. Also this would require users with the ability to change the DNS server they use.